# Set the hover background color of a Gtk3 MenuItem

Tags: python, css, gtk3

I have a tray icon with a popup menu.  I am trying to set the background color of the menu items in this popup.  I am able to set the text color but not the background color of the menu item.

[image]

The background that appears is the default Ubuntu orange, and I can't override it.

I've created a sample application that demonstrates this problem.  Just copy-paste it into a .py file and it should run.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
import sys

class TrayIcon:

    def __init__(self):
        self.statusicon = Gtk.StatusIcon()
        self.statusicon.set_from_stock(Gtk.STOCK_MEDIA_PLAY)
        self.statusicon.connect("popup-menu", self.OnShowPopupMenu)
        window = Gtk.Window()

    def OnShowPopupMenu(self, icon, button, time):
       menu = Gtk.Menu()
       first = self.GetMenuItem("First")
       second = self.GetMenuItem("Second")
       menu.append(first)
       menu.append(second)
       menu.show_all()
       menu.popup(None, None, lambda w,x: self.statusicon.position_menu(menu, self.statusicon), self.statusicon, 3, time)

    def GetMenuItem(self, txt):
    menuItem = Gtk.MenuItem(txt)

    screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()
    css_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
    #css_provider.load_from_data("GtkWidget { color:white; background-color: green; } GtkWidget:hover,GtkWidget:selected { color:white; background-color:pink;}")
    css_provider.load_from_data("GtkMenuItem { color:#0f0; background-color: #f00; } GtkMenuItem:hover,GtkMenuItem:selected { color:#00f; background-color:#f00; font-weight:bold;}")
    context = Gtk.StyleContext()
    context.add_provider_for_screen(screen, css_provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)

    menuItem.connect("button_press_event", self.exit)

    return menuItem

    def exit(self, a,b):
    sys.exit()

TrayIcon()
Gtk.main()
```

For GtkMenuItem the normal background and :hover background are being ignored.  For GtkWidget the :hover background is being ignored. My aim is to prevent that Ubuntu orange from showing up without disabling the menu item.

**Is there a way to set the background and hover/mouseover color of a GtkMenuItem? (without using 'import gtk')**

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, default theme.

**Edit1**: To add a bit of clarity, this is what I am trying to do, but without 'import gtk'.

```
    #Prevent background color when mouse hovers
    style = menuItem.get_style().copy()
    style.bg[gtk.STATE_SELECTED] = style.bg[gtk.STATE_NORMAL]
    menuItem.set_style(style)
```

**Edit2**:  I've also tried override_background_color() and modify_bg, and again, the orange still shows up on hover.  Here are variants of what I have tried.

```
    menuItem.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL,Gdk.RGBA(1.0,0.0,0.0,1))
    menuItem.modify_bg(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL,Gdk.color_parse("red"))
    menuItem.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, Gdk.RGBA(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
    menuItem.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.SELECTED, Gdk.RGBA(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
    menuItem.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.FOCUSED, Gdk.RGBA(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
```

**Edit3**:  Answer has been provided, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11491392/974369).

Comment: It's best not to change the color and background color without a really good reason. Some users have certain desktop themes and colors because of visual handicaps such as color-blindness and you will make your application unusable for these people.

Comment: Yep, but in this case there is a specific reason and requirement to change the background color, hence the question.  I'm deliberately not including the reasons as it's all internal office reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of digging, the answer turned out to be somewhat obscure.

- `background-color` does not work.  I had to use `background`
- I also had to use `-unico-inner-stroke-width`

I ended up at a GTK3 CSS file for the Ubuntu theme itself to see what was happening, located here:

```
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css
```

I got the `-unico-inner-stroke-width` property from the CSS file above.  I cannot determine why `background-color` in my script is being ignored, but it is, at least on Ubuntu 12.04.

I was also forced to 're-set' the background and border colors of the elements I was changing as they would otherwise appear strange.  This is the minimum CSS I had to use

```
                    GtkMenuItem 
                    {
                        border:@bg_color;
                        background:@bg_color;
                    }

                    GtkMenuItem:hover
                    {
                        background:@selected_bg_color;
                    }

                    GtkWidget
                    {
                        border: @bg_color;
                    }

                    #mymenu:hover
                    {
                        color:@fg_color;
                        background: @bg_color;
                        -unico-inner-stroke-width: 0;
                    }
```

In this example, I am setting the hover color of a single GtkMenuItem to be the same as the background color, but if you want to set the color to something else, you'd have to change the `background` property as per your needs.

Result, a working MenuItem without a hover color

[image]

Here is the full Python code:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
import sys


class TrayIcon:

    def __init__(self):
        self.statusicon = Gtk.StatusIcon()
        self.statusicon.set_from_stock(Gtk.STOCK_MEDIA_PLAY)
        self.statusicon.connect("popup-menu", self.OnShowPopupMenu)
        self.statusicon.set_tooltip_text("HELLO")
        window = Gtk.Window()

    def OnShowPopupMenu(self, icon, button, time):

        display = Gdk.Display.get_default()
        screen = display.get_default_screen()

        css_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()

        gtk3Css = """GtkMenuItem {
                        border:@bg_color;
                        background:@bg_color;
                    }

                    GtkMenuItem:hover
                    {
                        background:@selected_bg_color;
                    }

                    GtkWidget
                    {
                        border: @bg_color;
                    }

                    #mymenu:hover
                    {
                        color:@fg_color;
                        background: @bg_color;
                        -unico-inner-stroke-width: 0;
                    }"""
        css_provider.load_from_data(gtk3Css)
        context = Gtk.StyleContext()
        context.add_provider_for_screen(screen, css_provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)

        menu = Gtk.Menu()
        #menu.set_name('mymenu')
        first = self.GetMenuItem("First")
        first.set_name('mymenu')
        second = self.GetMenuItem("Second")
        menu.append(first)
        menu.append(second)
        menu.show_all()
        menu.popup(None, None, lambda w,x: self.statusicon.position_menu(menu, self.statusicon), self.statusicon, 3, time)

    def GetMenuItem(self, txt):
    menuItem = Gtk.MenuItem()
    menuItem.set_label(txt)

    menuItem.connect("button_press_event", self.exit)

    return menuItem

    def exit(self, a,b):
    sys.exit()


TrayIcon()
Gtk.main()
```

If you wanted to set another background color, you could do this in the CSS above

```
                    GtkMenuItem:hover
                    {
                        background:purple;
                        -unico-inner-stroke-width: 0;
                    }
```

(or do it in #mymenu:hover)

[image]

In conclusion, I think this may have been a problem limited to Ubuntu 12.04 or GTK 3.4.2 which I determined by running,

```
pkg-config --modversion gtk+-3.0
```

But I do not have the expertise to determine the origin of this problem.

Comment: Sorry for necro-posting...
background-color "not working" is often because themes set a gradient using background-image. So the background-color is technically working, just hidden behind the background "image". Using "background-image: none;" makes it work.

Comment: Using just "background" also works, because it is a shorthand for many properties including -color and -image.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's C not python, but this works for me. I named the menu "mymenu" that way you can style it without using GtkLabel which would affect any other labels in the application.

```
/* COMPILE WITH: gcc -Wall -o icon3 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` icon3.c */

#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <string.h>  /* for CSS */

static void cb_left_click(GtkStatusIcon *icon, gpointer data)
{
 static GtkWidget *window = NULL;

if (window == NULL) {
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Status Icon");

    g_signal_connect( window, "delete-event", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL );
    gtk_widget_show(window);
}
}

static void cb_right_click(GtkStatusIcon *icon, int button, int time, gpointer data)
{
    GtkWidget *menu;

menu = gtk_menu_new ();
gtk_widget_set_name(GTK_WIDGET(menu),"mymenu");
GtkWidget *item1 = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("First");

GtkWidget *item2 = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Second");

gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu), item1);
gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu), item2);

    gtk_widget_show_all(menu);
    gtk_menu_popup(GTK_MENU(menu),
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        gtk_status_icon_position_menu,
                        icon,
                        button,
                        time);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
GtkStatusIcon *icon;
/*-- CSS ------------------*/
  GtkCssProvider *provider;
  GdkDisplay *display;
  GdkScreen *screen;
/*---------------------------*/

gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

icon = gtk_status_icon_new_from_stock (GTK_STOCK_MEDIA_PLAY);

g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT(icon), "activate", G_CALLBACK(cb_left_click), NULL);
g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT(icon), "popup-menu", G_CALLBACK(cb_right_click), NULL);

/*---------------- CSS ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
  display = gdk_display_get_default ();
  screen = gdk_display_get_default_screen (display);
  gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen (screen, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER (provider),     GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);

  gsize bytes_written, bytes_read;

 const gchar* home = "/home/mike/icon3.css";     

  GError *error = 0;

  gtk_css_provider_load_from_path (provider,
                               g_filename_to_utf8(home, strlen(home),
                               &bytes_read, &bytes_written, &error),
                               NULL);
  g_object_unref (provider);
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Css file:

```
#mymenu {       
    background-color: white;
    color: green;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#mymenu :hover {
    background-color: red;
    color: blue;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Being unfamiliar with C, I'm struggling to get this to work.  To the best of my translation abilities, this is the same as what I am doing, the difference is that you're using #mymenu instead of the type. Regardless, the background isn't being set.  Are you on Ubuntu as well, could you post a screenshot of it in action?   When I attempt to compile it as shown in the commented part of the code, I get several [undefined errors](http://i.imgur.com/LfsQB.png). I would prefer Python, since I'm unsure if something being done in the C code above that would count as a missing step in my own code.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu Natty, gtk+-3.2.3. Sorry I don't know Python at all. In your function css_provider.load_from_data() you have the same background-color for the normal state as you do for the hover and selected states: #f00. http://img809.imageshack.us/img809/1474/iconcd.png

Comment: I finally found it, and it may have had to do with the difference in our Ubuntu or GTK3 versions.  I've posted my answer separately.  Thanks for your efforts though and at least looking at the question.