# GTK3 CSS colors not respected - even in official example

Tags: css, c, gtk3

I've been suffering with a simple task: I want to make a GtkLabel's background and text another color. I've read *many* pages, and as such also tried to put an EventBox behind the label and changeing the box's bg color instead. All to no avail.

Then I came across [this tutorial](http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?p=195276#p195276), which I copied, compiled without change, and it has the same problem: The background isn't yellow, and the text isn't blue, as they are supposed to be. I even tried replacing the 'yellow' color by rgba(255, 127, 127, 1) to be sure there was no transparency.

An extra fact: The font is being changed correctly! So the CSS is really being interpreted.

So, why doesn't this work? (I've come across another user with the exactly same problem - no solution though).

Suspecting: is it possible that the theme is somehow blocking later changes? 
I would suppose that later defined CSS should override any theme definition?

Note: I'm using gtk 3.12.2

Edit: I Changed the theme to default Adwaita, and the background changed to light, but not to the color indicated in the program. The text color did not change. [image: Screenshot with Adwaita theme]

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar problem - for me, putting:

```
background-image: none;
```

into my CSS resolved the situation - I guess some themes have background images which block the background color from being displayed

Comment: Thanks for replying... The issue is a little old, and Gtk3 and its CSS have change a lot since then. I believe we're at 3.22 now.

Answer (score 0):

to start, it strongly depends on which colour pallet is selected/default.

second, colour bytes are defined as 0...255, not 0.5

Comment: Mmmm... I think I've read most of the docs, and I did not find anything about pallets in GTK3 - I thought most color definitions would be un-palleted by now? About the color definition, yes... you're right. The decimal representation is used elsewhere in GTK. But using background-color: rgba(255, 123, 123, 255) does not solve the problem. Thanks for the reply though!

Answer (score 0):

With some themes you might need "background" instead of "background-color".
[Set the hover background color of a Gtk3 MenuItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381401/set-the-hover-background-color-of-a-gtk3-menuitem/11459904#11459904)

As far as the text color being ignored, it might be due to the theme. Try another theme, and/or try one of the other color units. CSS for Gtk3 works with: Basic color keywords, X11 extended, RGB(integers or integer percentages), RGBA and hexadecimal.

According to the GTK+ roadmap all style properties will be deprecated after 3.18 and before 4.0 anyway. 
https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK+/Roadmap

They were supposed to be merging Clutter into GTK+ by v4.0 but now I hear things about GSK so I don't know what their going to do. 
https://www.bassi.io/articles/2014/07/29/guadec-2014-gsk/